# cannot anymore import Brightway2 - ImportError

Tags: brightway

I tried to import brightway2 as usual and it worked but now it does'nt work anymore and get an  : 
 **ImportError: cannot import name 'databases'**
I didn't change anything, I tried to remove conda and install again but same error...Any ideas?

```
import brightway2 as bw
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-a3ddbb8a34e8> in <module>
----> 1 import brightway2 as bw

D:\Users\gressetbourgeoismat\Documents\Portable\miniconda\envs\bw6\lib\site-packages\brightway2\__init__.py in <module>
      1 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*
----> 2 from bw2data import *
      3 from bw2calc import *
      4 from bw2io import *
      5 

D:\Users\gressetbourgeoismat\Documents\Portable\miniconda\envs\bw6\lib\site-packages\bw2data\__init__.py in <module>
     33 from .project import projects
     34 from .utils import set_data_dir
---> 35 from .meta import (
     36     dynamic_calculation_setups,
     37     calculation_setups,

D:\Users\gressetbourgeoismat\Documents\Portable\miniconda\envs\bw6\lib\site-packages\bw2data\meta.py in <module>
    190 preferences = Preferences()
    191 weightings = WeightingMeta()
--> 192 calculation_setups = CalculationSetups()
    193 dynamic_calculation_setups = DynamicCalculationSetups()

D:\Users\gressetbourgeoismat\Documents\Portable\miniconda\envs\bw6\lib\site-packages\bw2data\serialization.py in __init__(self, dirpath)
    120             self.filename
    121         )
--> 122         self.load()
    123 
    124     def load(self):

D:\Users\gressetbourgeoismat\Documents\Portable\miniconda\envs\bw6\lib\site-packages\bw2data\serialization.py in load(self)
    125         """Load the serialized data. Creates the file if not yet present."""
    126         try:
--> 127             self.data = self.deserialize()
    128         except IOError:
    129             # Create if not present

D:\Users\gressetbourgeoismat\Documents\Portable\miniconda\envs\bw6\lib\site-packages\bw2data\serialization.py in deserialize(self)
    238 
    239     def deserialize(self):
--> 240         return self.unpack(pickle.load(open(self.filepath, "rb")))
    241 
    242 

D:\Users\gressetbourgeoismat\Documents\Portable\miniconda\envs\bw6\lib\site-packages\bw2data\backends\__init__.py in <module>
      3 from eight import *
      4 
----> 5 from .base import LCIBackend
      6 from .peewee import SQLiteBackend
      7 from .json import JSONDatabase
```

And Something missing ?

```
D:\Users\gressetbourgeoismat\Documents\Portable\miniconda\envs\bw6\lib\site-packages\bw2data\backends\base.py in <module>
      3 from eight import *
      4 
----> 5 from .. import (
      6     config,
      7     databases,

ImportError: cannot import name 'databases'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug, and will be [fixed in an upcoming release](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-data/commit/9c52e76c84bfa7d3d9719da152c0616d4039a3c3). For the time being, you need to delete the file:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<User>\Application Data\Local Settings\pylca\Brightway3\<default-something>\setups.pickle
```

Comment: Ok, perfect. It works! Before to see your answer I delete all files in C:\Documents and Settings\<User>\Application Data\Local Settings\pylca\Brightway3\                      and install again. thxs